# Different definitions of (anti-)exchange for a closure operator

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, matroids

1. [Wikipedia article for matroids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid) says

   > For all elements $a$, and $b$ of $E$ and all subsets $Y$ of $E$, if $a\in\operatorname{cl}(Y\cup b) \setminus Y$ then
   >   $b\in\operatorname{cl}(Y\cup a) \setminus Y.$
   >   ... (it) is sometimes called the Mac Lane–Steinitz exchange property.

   [Another article for closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator#Closure_operators_in_algebra) says:

   > the exchange property: If $x$ is in the closure of the union of $A$ and $\{y\}$ but not in the closure of $A$, then $y$ is in the
   >   closure of the union of $A$ and $\{x\}$.

   As far as I can tell they seem not equivalent, because the first one
   writes $a$ not in $Y$, and second one writes $x$ not in the closure
   of $A$. So I wonder if one of them is wrong for defining the
   exchange property, or I fail to see their equivalence?
2. I am also not able to see if the following two definitions of the
   anti-exchange property for a closure operator are equivalent: from
   [antimatroid at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatroid):

   > anti-exchange axiom:  If neither $y$ nor $z$ belong to $τ(S)$, but $z$ belongs to $τ(S \cup \{y\})$, then $y$ does not belong to $τ(S\cup \{z\})$.

   from [closure at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator#Closure_operators_in_algebra):

   > the anti-exchange property: If $x$ is not contained in the union of $A$ and $\{y\}$, but in its closure, then $y$ is not contained in
   >   the closure of the union of $A$ and $\{x\}$.

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: The first of the quoted exchange properties is wrong as it stands.  It would become correct (and equivalent to the second version) if it were restricted to closed sets $Y$.

Question 2: The first quoted version is again wrong, but only because it neglects to exclude the possibility that $y=z$.  If you add $y\neq z$ to the hypotheses, then it becomes correct.  The second version is also wrong (consider the case where $x$ and $y$ are distinct points in the closure of $A$), but it becomes correct if you add the hypothesis that $A$ is closed.

Comment: Thanks! What are some standard references for the definitions? I guess the definitions are same for (anti)matroids and outside (anti)matroids, as long as there is a closure operator (defined in its [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator))?

Comment: Can the anti-exchange property be defined equivalently as "If $y \neq z$ and neither $y$ nor $z$ belong to $τ(S)$, then $z$ belongs to $τ(S∪{y})$ if and only if $y$ does not belong to $τ(S∪{z})$"? (I ask this, because I saw elsewhere the exchange property can be defined equivalently as "If  neither $y$ nor $z$ belong to $τ(S)$, then $z$ belongs to $τ(S∪{y})$ if and only if $y$  not belong to $τ(S∪{z})$", which I assume is correct.)